# When does '?' in regex act as non-greedy matcher and when does it mean a pattern is optional?

Tags: regex

I am a beginner to regex.

I read that '?' in a regex means a pattern is optional also when it is used after a '+' or '*', the '?' can be used for a non-greedy match.

I have tried this on regex101, here is the link - https://regex101.com/r/rV5sW5/1. I don't find the non greedy match happening here. Need help understanding this.

Comment: Looks non-greedy to me -- it's matching the smallest number of spaces possible (i.e., zero).

Comment: Non-greedy means the first occurrence right?

Comment: No, non-greedy means it matches the smallest possible number of occurrences, instead of the default behavior of matching the largest possible number of occurrences.

Comment: It sounds like you're confusing greedy with global. You're using the global flag ("/g"), and the "Explanation" box explains what that means, i.e., return all matches. Greedy and global are independent and have nothing to do with each other.

Comment: Ok. I get it now. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`?` means non-greedy (also called "reluctant") when it follows an asterisk `*` or a plus `+` repetition constructs.

In your case question mark definitely acts as non-greedy qualifier, because `\s*?` matches nothing. That is exactly the expected behavior for `*?` - it means "match as little as possible", so when it is possible to match nothing, the sub-expression matches nothing.

Comment: Is it not supposed to match the first occurrence only?

Comment: @MukundGandlur No, because you specified "global" option `g` to the right of the expression.

Comment: More generally, `?` turns any quantifier to non-greedy.  There are other quantifiers than `*` and `+` -- numbered repetition `{1,2}` and optional `?` come immediately to mind.  Maybe I'm still missing some.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a quick example.  Given the text

```
aaaaaabbb
```

applying the regex

```
a+(.)
```

with a greedy quantifier will match as many `a` characters as possible, and return `b` in the captured group.  By contrast,

```
a+?(.)
```

matches only the first `a`, because that's the shortest possible match, and returns (the second) `a` in the captured group.

Anywhere else than behind a quantifier (`*` or `+`, etc) a question mark has its regular ERE meaning of optional element (a shorthand for the generalized quantifier `{0,1}`; and you can make a non-greedy optional with `??` and a non-greedy generalized quantifier with `{3,7}?`, too!)

Maybe also note that non-greedy quantifiers are a relatively recent addition to regular expressions (introduced in Perl 5) and not available at all in many dialects.